# Android apk in debug mode

Tags: android, debugging

I have some questions about debug mode. I have app with file buildconfig.debug where is

`debug = true`

1. Is that means, my app is in debug mode
2. How can I change this in debug=false
3. Can I set android:debuggable="false" in manifest so that my app be in relase mode

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The easiest way to create a signed apk if you're using Eclipse with the ADT plugin, just click File->Export and the Export Wizard will guide you through the process.

"To export an unsigned APK from Eclipse, right-click the project in the Package Explorer and select Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package." Then you have to sign it using the Jarsigner tool, etc. See the instructions link below. There are also instructions for if you're not using Eclipse.

[Link to Instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile)

Make sure you uninstall the debug mode apk from your device before installing the release mode apk or you might get problems.

Comment: But when I export my app, in file buildconfig.debug there is a debug = true, and I don't wanna upload debug app on android market

Comment: Could be you have this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940. Not sure how to help except you could try using ant to build it. Or check with Google to see if there's a fix.

Comment: Yes I have that problem. I will try to build with ant. But how to check is my apk debug? On this link I see "The size of my APK suggests that it really is RELEASE - so I assume this bug is just that DEBUG flag doesn't work". How to see this?

Comment: Not sure how to check that. Try this: "I use the following workaround:

1. Disable "Project > Build Automatically"
2. Project > Clean
3. Project > Build All
4. Export Project"

Comment: No use. Is there a problem to upload debugged game on market?

Comment: I try with ant and I have this situation: I have apk file build with ant and I try to signed it. I use kaystore from eclipse (eclipse create it when I try to export project with it). and I use command jarsigner -verbose -keystore linkToKeyStore linkToAPK myKeyStoreAliase   And I have error "jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: myAliase.  myAliase must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain."